# Discrete Math cardinality finding out

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Finding cardinality of the set

For all x less than 100, x/10 is set of Natural number Union 0.

Is the answer 9?

Comment: Do you want to find the cardinality of $\left\{x\in \Bbb N\colon x<100 \land \dfrac{x}{10}\in \Bbb N\right\}\cup \{0\}$?

Answer (score 1):

Your question, as currently stated, doesn't make sense grammatically.  However, as Git Gud pointed out in the comment above, it is likely that you're referring to the set
$$
\left\{x\in \Bbb N\colon x<100 \land \dfrac{x}{10}\in \Bbb N\right\}\cup \{0\}
$$
Or, to state the same with fewer symbols: *the union of (the set of positive numbers x such that $x<100$ and $x/10$ is a Natural number) with (zero)*.  You never actually specified whether $x$ needs to be positive and whether $x$ is meant to be a natural number, but given the limited information you provided this is what makes the most sense.

If this is what you are looking for, you would note that
$$
\left\{x\in \Bbb N\colon x<100 \land \dfrac{x}{10}\in \Bbb N\right\} =
\{10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90\}
$$
And taking the union of this set gives you
$$
\left\{x\in \Bbb N\colon x<100 \land \dfrac{x}{10}\in \Bbb N\right\}\cup \{0\} =
\{0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90\}
$$
Since the above set contains $10$ elements, **the cardinality of the resulting set is $\mathbf{10}$**.